# Unable to delete project in Action Console

Tags: delete-file

I'm trying to delete the display of two projects in the Action Console.  I created both but then deleted these projects using the usual method but the names still show up in the console.  Clicking on the projects gives a "There was an error completing your request...Try again".  No matter how often I "try again" I get the same message.  These projects were deleted and do not exist, I'm just trying to keep them from displaying in the "Your projects" list.

I went to the Google Cloud Platform and these two projects do not exists. I wrote the google support but their suggestion of clearing the browser (chrome) cache didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try open it in different browser? But you should resolve this issue with Google support.

Comment: Tried Firefox, explorer, chrome, and edge for no joy.  Tried google support and was told to clear my cache which also did not prove effective.  Thanks for answering, though.  Any advise is always appreciated.